# VBA for Global PowerPoint Character Spacing Normalization

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to come up with a solution to normalize all character spacing across all slides in a single PowerPoint document in one go. I have come up with a macros that do it for all shapes **but it keeps skipping text in tables**. However, when I add msoTable into the range it starts processing the slides but when it hits the first table it immediately returns a run-time error claiming that the specified value is out of range.

Any idea what is wrong? Pretty sure it is a simple fix.

```
Sub SpacingNormalization()
On Error GoTo ErrMsg 
Dim shape As shape
slideCount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
For i = 1 To slideCount
With ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
.Select
For Each shape In ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes
If shape.Type = msoPlaceholder Or shape.Type = msoTextBox Or shape.Type = msoAutoShape Or shape.Type = msoTable Then
shape.Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 0
End If
ErrMsg:
Next
End With
Next
MsgBox ("All segments have been normalized!")
End Sub
```

Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First rule of automating PPT:  Never select anything unless you absolutely have to.
Second rule of automating PPT: You almost never have to.

Modified your code accordingly.

And in most cases you have to step through a table cell by cell to modify anything.  More mods.  See below:

```
Sub SpacingNormalization()
On Error GoTo ErrMsg 
' It's unwise to use PPT keywords as variable names:
' Dim shape As shape
Dim oSh as Shape
Dim oSl as Slide

For each oSl in ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes

If oSh.Type = msoPlaceholder Or oSh.Type = msoTextBox Or oSh.Type = msoAutoShape Then

oSh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 0

Else 
If  oSh.Type = msoTable then
  Call ProcessTable(oSh.Table)
end if  ' Table
End If  ' Other types
Next ' oSh
Next ' oSl


NormalExit:
MsgBox ("All segments have been normalized!")
Exit Sub
ErrMsg:
Resume Next

End Sub

Sub ProcessTable(oTbl As Table)

    Dim Col As Long
    Dim Row As Long

    With oTbl
        For Col = 1 To .Columns.Count
            For Row = 1 To .Rows.Count
                .Cell(Row, Col).Shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 0
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your input. Tried testing your script and it does not appear to be functional. VBA in PowerPoint cycles through it fine fixing spacing for all shapes (which my initial script can do already), yet it would still not fix tables. It seems it is skipping the Call of the second sub. The editor displays it as a separate sub and there is no way to run it separately. Tried consolidating into one single sub but failed. The new one that I came up (with Case Is =) with seems to be working but unfortunately I had to write it from scratch and it is a completely different script now.

Comment: My bad ... see edited version;  I changed Call ProcessTable(oSh) to  Call ProcessTable(oSh.Table) and it works now.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that a shape which is type placeholder may be a table too. So, you could check the ContainedType property on the PlaceholderFormat object for Placeholders or use the HasTable property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one that I came up with. It is within only one sub and seems to be a little bit more straightforward:

```
Sub SpacingNormalization()
        On Error GoTo Errmsg
        Dim oshp As shape
        Dim otbl As Table
        Dim Rws As Integer
        Dim Clms As Integer
        Dim osld As Slide
        For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            For Each oshp In osld.Shapes
                Select Case oshp.HasTable
                Case Is = True
                    Set otbl = oshp.Table
                    For Rws = 1 To otbl.Rows.Count
                        For Clms = 1 To otbl.Columns.Count
                            otbl.Cell(Rws, Clms).shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 0
                        Next Clms
                    Next Rws
                Case Is = False
                    If oshp.HasTextFrame Then
                        If oshp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                            oshp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 0
                        End If
                    End If
                End Select
            Next oshp
        Next osld
        MsgBox ("All segments have been normalized!")
        Exit Sub
Errmsg:
        MsgBox "Error"
    End Sub
```